# ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 17 for 'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,17]

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i am trying to implement Alexnet for the detection of diabetic retinopathy.
here is the code

```
path="D:\\dataset\\train\\t\\"

count = 1
imgList=list()
labelList=list()
ite = 1

print("Loading Model design ....")
json_file = open('Model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

print("Loading weights ....")
loaded_model.load_weights("Model_weight.h5")

opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
loaded_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

while ite <= 1:
    limit = 10 * ite
    imgList=list()
    labelList=list()
    while count <= limit:
        imgC0 = path+"class_0_img_%d.jpeg" %(count)
        imgC1 = path+"class_1_img_%d.jpeg" %(count)
        imgC2 = path+"class_2_img_%d.jpeg" %(count)
        imgC3 = path+"class_3_img_%d.jpeg" %(count)
        imgC4 = path+"class_4_img_%d.jpeg" %(count)

        lC0 = np.zeros((1,17))
        lC1 = np.zeros((1,17))
        lC2 = np.zeros((1,17))
        lC3 = np.zeros((1,17))
        lC4 = np.zeros((1,17))

        lC0[0,0] = 1
        lC1[0,1] = 1
        lC2[0,2] = 1
        lC2[0,3] = 1
        lC2[0,4] = 1

        im0=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgC0),(227,227))
        im1=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgC1),(227,227))
        im2=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgC2),(227,227))
        im3=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgC3),(227,227))
        im4=cv.resize(cv.imread(imgC4),(227,227))

        imgList.append(im0)
        imgList.append(im1)
        imgList.append(im2)
        imgList.append(im3)
        imgList.append(im4)

        labelList.append(lC0)
        labelList.append(lC1)
        labelList.append(lC2)
        labelList.append(lC3)
        labelList.append(lC4)

        print(count)

        del(imgC0)
        del(imgC1)
        del(imgC2)
        del(imgC3)
        del(imgC4)
        del(lC0)
        del(lC1)
        del(lC2)
        del(lC3)
        del(lC4)
        count += 1

    labelMatrix = labelList

    xtr = np.array(imgList)
    xtr = xtr.reshape(-1,227,227,3)
    ytr = np.array(labelMatrix)
    ytr = ytr.reshape(-1,17)

    print(xtr.shape)
    print(ytr.shape)

    print(type(ytr))

    print("Model Training ....")
    loaded_model.fit(xtr,ytr,epochs=1,batch_size=50,validation_split=0.1)

    print("Saving Model weights ....")
    #loaded_model.save_weights("Model_weight.h5")

    ite += 1
    del(imgList)
    del(labelList)

print("Finished ....")
```

i am getting an error as:

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('D:/Project/ModelTrain.py', wdir='D:/Project')

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "D:/Project/ModelTrain.py", line 103, in 
    loaded_model.fit(xtr,ytr,epochs=1,batch_size=50,validation_split=0.1)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 728, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 324, in fit
    total_epochs=epochs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py", line 123, in run_one_epoch
    batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 86, in execution_function
    distributed_function(input_fn))

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 457, in **call**
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 503, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 408, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1848, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2150, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 2041, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 915, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\def_function.py", line 358, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 73, in distributed_function
    per_replica_function, args=(model, x, y, sample_weights))

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 760, in experimental_run_v2
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 1787, in call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 2132, in _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 292, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2_utils.py", line 264, in train_on_batch
    output_loss_metrics=model._output_loss_metrics)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 315, in train_on_batch
    model, outs, targets, sample_weights=sample_weights, masks=masks)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_eager.py", line 74, in _eager_metrics_fn
    skip_target_masks=model._prepare_skip_target_masks())

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2063, in _handle_metrics
    target, output, output_mask))

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2014, in _handle_per_output_metrics
    metric_fn, y_true, y_pred, weights=weights, mask=mask)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 1067, in call_metric_function
    return metric_fn(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=weights)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\metrics.py", line 193, in **call**
    replica_local_fn, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\distribute\distributed_training_utils.py", line 1135, in call_replica_local_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\metrics.py", line 176, in replica_local_fn
    update_op = self.update_state(*args, **kwargs)  # pylint: disable=not-callable

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 75, in decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\metrics.py", line 581, in update_state
    matches = self._fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\metrics.py", line 2778, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
    y_true = array_ops.squeeze(y_true, [-1])

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\dispatch.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 3649, in squeeze
    return gen_array_ops.squeeze(input, axis, name)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 10071, in squeeze
    "Squeeze", input=input, squeeze_dims=axis, name=name)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 793, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 548, in create_op
    compute_device)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3429, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1773, in **init**
    control_input_ops)

File "C:\Users\Ammar Ameer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1613, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 17 for 'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,17].

can anyone help me on this..
i have saved the model as

```
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227,227,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding="valid", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5,5), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding="same", activation = "relu"))

# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding="valid"))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(units = 9216, activation = "relu"))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(units = 4096, activation = "relu"))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, activation = "relu"))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17, activation = "softmax")) #As we have two classes

opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()


model_jason = model.to_json()
with open("Model.json","w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_jason)

model.save_weights("Model_weight.h5")
```

pls help me to solve this..

Comment: I think there is a mismatch between the number of outputs your model is providing and your target variable(s)? It is not clear to me why the dimensionality of output dense layer is 17 and not 1 or 2 (depending on how you encode a binary classification). Perhaps you can provide an example y target.

Comment: Why is `lC0` etc (1,17)? And as an aside  all those `del` are useless.  You already inserted those objects into lists.